# R Code : Error in (function: arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2

Tags: r, numbers, arguments, rows

The following part of the code works fine for me. assessments_jobSmart is an imported csv file. I'm trying to reshape data of multiple column but i couldn't make it by using tapply. So i attempted to bind the matrices by matching user_id, and add row id the id hasn't existed.

```
individual_assess <- filter(assessments_jobSmart, !is.na(assessments_jobSmart$submitted))
quiz_i = filter(individual_assess, assessment_type == 'quiz')
checkin_i = filter(individual_assess, assessment_type == 'checkin')


groupQuiz_i <- group_by(quiz_i, user_id, program_id, name)
summaryQuiz_i <- summarize(groupQuiz_i, maxQuiz = max(moderated_score))
q1 <- with(summaryQuiz_i, tapply(maxQuiz, list(user_id, name) , I))
q2=matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(q1), ncol = ncol(q1)+1)
colnames(q2) = c("user_id", paste("assess_q", colnames(q1)))
q2[1:nrow(q2),1] = rownames(q1)
q2[1:nrow(q2),2:ncol(q2)] = q1[1:nrow(q1),1:ncol(q1)]
lla = merge(lla, q2, by = 'user_id', all=TRUE)
```

But for the next part, it gives me error at the end of my last line. I reffered to many links but still can't figure out why. c1 and c2 both have same number of rows.

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = 
TRUE, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2
```

faulty code:

```
groupCheckin_i <- group_by(checkin_i, user_id, program_id, name)
summaryCheckin_i <- summarize(groupCheckin_i, countCheckin = n())
c1 <- with(summaryCheckin_i, tapply(countCheckin, list(user_id, name) , I))
c1[c1=="NULL"]=NA
c2=matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(c1), ncol = ncol(c1)+1)
colnames(c2) = c("user_id", paste("assess_c", colnames(c1)))
c2[1:nrow(c2),1] = rownames(c1)
c2[1:nrow(c2),2:ncol(c2)] = c1[1:nrow(c1),1:ncol(c1)]
lla = merge(lla, c2, by = 'user_id', all=TRUE)
```

Reproducible example, not sure if i replicate it correctly tho. I'll start from the dataframe imported, grouped, and summarized.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("reshape2")
install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE) 
library("dplyr")
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

head = c("user_id", "program", "assessment", "type", "marks")
content = c("111", "program A", "quiz 1", "quiz", "1", "112", "program A", "quiz 1", "quiz", "0.5", "112", "program A", "quiz 2", "quiz", "0.75", "113", "program B", "quiz 2", "quiz", "0.8", "110", "program B", "survey 1", "survey", "1", "113", "program B", "survey 1", "survey", "1")
M = as.dataframe(matrix(content, nrow=5, ncol=5)) #kinda replicate my imported csv file.
s = filter(M, type == 'survey')
q = filter(M, type == 'quiz')
groupS = group_by(s, user_id, program, assessment)
groupQ = group_by(q, user_id, program, assessment)

summaryS <- summarize(groupS, maxMarks = max(marks)) # take only maximum marks if there are duplicate entries
s1 <- with(summaryS, tapply(maxMarks, list(user_id, assessment) , I))
s2 = matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(s1), ncol=ncol(s1)+1)
colnames(s2) = c("user_id", colnames(s1))
s2[q:nrow(s2), 1] = rownames(s1)      # everything works alright till here
s2[1:nrow(s2),2:ncol(s2)] = s1[1:nrow(s1),1:nrow(s1)]

summaryQ <- summarize(groupQ, count = n()) # it makes more sense to count survey done
q1 <- with(summaryQ, tapply(count, list(user_id, assessment) , I))
q2 = matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(q1), ncol=ncol(q1)+1)
colnames(q2) = c("user_id", colnames(q1))
q2[q:nrow(q2), 1] = rownames(q1)      # everything works alright till here
q2[1:nrow(q2),2:ncol(q2)] = q1[1:nrow(q1),1:nrow(q1)]  #q2 becomes a list :(
b = merge(b, a2, by = 'user_id', all+TRUE)


#     | program   | assessment   | marks
# ---------------------------------------
# 111 | program A | quiz 1       | 1
# 112 | program A | quiz 1       | 0.5
# 112 | program A | quiz 2       | 0.75
# 113 | program B | quiz 2       | 0.8

# Then I used tapply to reshape data to get something like:

#     | assessment 1 | assessment 2
# -------------------------------------
# 111 | 1            | NA
# 112 | 0.5          | 0.75
# 113 | NA           | 0.8
```

There are many of these tables because the results are extracted differently, so I want to merge them at the end to combine all the results. I don't want user_id to appear twice, each for separate table. I want to compare results with user_id but heading for that column is missing as user_id was treated as rownames. So I create a larger matrix to copy everything and include the user_id column name:

```
# Let's say a1 is the matrix after tapply, a2 is the new dataframe I want to create, b is the successful new dataframe created using the exact same method on same csv file exported.
```

I want to get something like this after merging:

```
user_id | survey 1 | survey 2 | assessment 1 | assessment 2
-------------------------------------------------------------
110     | 1        | NA       | NA           | NA
111     | NA       | NA       | 1            | NA
112     | NA       | NA       | 0.5          | 0.75
113     | 1        | NA       | NA           | 0.8
```

Comment: If you can include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: I have added the sample. Please let me know if this is sufficient

Comment: It's nice to see the examples like you've added, but people can't easily load that into R to work out solutions. You should look at the examples in the link I gave earlier and try using `dput()` for example.

Comment: Done. But not sure if they are close enough to my imported csv file

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a hard time understanding exactly what you are starting with and what you want. And some parts of your reproducible example do not work. I tried to fill in the blanks and so here's my attempt at answering.

Instead of all the apply functions, you might want to try [`tidyr`](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/) functions for reshaping dataframes (`gather`/ `spread` and `unite`/`separate`).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 <- data_frame(
           V1 = c("111", "program A", "quiz 1", "quiz", "1"),
           V2 = c("112", "program A", "quiz 1", "quiz", "0.5"),
           V3 = c("112", "program A", "quiz 2", "quiz", "0.75"),
           V4 = c("113", "program B", "quiz 2", "quiz", "0.8"),
           V5 = c("110", "program B", "survey 1", "survey", "1")
)

df1
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
#>       <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>
#> 1       111       112       112       113       110
#> 2 program A program A program A program B program B
#> 3    quiz 1    quiz 1    quiz 2    quiz 2  survey 1
#> 4      quiz      quiz      quiz      quiz    survey
#> 5         1       0.5      0.75       0.8         1

col_names <- c("user_id", "program", "assessment", "type", "marks")

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  summarise_all(paste, collapse = ",") %>%
  gather("key", "val") %>% 
  separate(val, col_names, ",", convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(assessment = assessment %>% str_extract("\\d") %>% as.integer(),
         program = str_extract(program, ".{1}$")) %>% 
  select(-key)

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   user_id program assessment   type marks
#>     <int>   <chr>      <int>  <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     111       A          1   quiz  1.00
#> 2     112       A          1   quiz  0.50
#> 3     112       A          2   quiz  0.75
#> 4     113       B          2   quiz  0.80
#> 5     110       B          1 survey  1.00

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(user_id, program, type, assessment) %>% 
  summarise(marks = max(marks)) %>% 
  unite(key, program, type, assessment) %>% 
  spread(key, marks)

df3
#> Source: local data frame [4 x 5]
#> Groups: user_id [4]
#> 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   user_id A_quiz_1 A_quiz_2 B_quiz_2 B_survey_1
#> *   <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1     110       NA       NA       NA          1
#> 2     111      1.0       NA       NA         NA
#> 3     112      0.5     0.75       NA         NA
#> 4     113       NA       NA      0.8         NA
```

You also mention something about having trouble with `user_id` being stuck as the rownames for some data. [`tibble::rownames_to_column()`](http://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/rownames.html) is helpful for this.

```r
library(tibble)

head(mtcars)
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model") %>% 
  head()
#>               model  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#> 6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Also, since you are using a lot of `tidyverse` functions, you might want to check out [`dplyr::*_join`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) functions instead of merge.

Comment: Thanks! rowname_to_column() helps :) Sorry, I'm really new to R

Comment: No problem @Wonniewonwon, glad it helps. That one's kinda a hidden gem. For learning more about tidyverse I've found [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/) really helpful.